# Duality for actions of H-spaces

Tags: homotopy-theory, duality-theorems

I am thinking about two duality theorems for H-spaces and their actions.

By H-space is meant a commutative monoid in the derived (homotopy) category of based connected CW-complexes. We can consider the actions of an H-space, which produce monoid actions in the derived (homotopy) category. We can also define $- \wedge_A -$ and [-,-]${}_A$ for an H-space $A$.

Let A be an H space and let X be an A-action. I am interested in these basic conditions involving duality in this setting:

- Can you characterize when there is a weak equivalence $[[X,A],A] \cong X$ (respectively, homotopy equivalence).
- Can you characterize when there is a weak equivalence $[X,Y] \cong [X,A] \wedge Y$?